# My flutter app is refusing to build with tesseract_ocr package

Tags: android, flutter, dart, tesseract

I am building an app that uses tesseract_ocr to get text from images. I configured it how I was asked to, but it failed to build with an error

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':tesseract_ocr:bundleDebugAar'.
> Direct local .aar file dependencies are not supported when building an AAR. The resulting AAR would be broken because the classes and Android resources from any local .aar file dependencies would not be packaged in the resulting AAR. Previous versions of the Android Gradle Plugin produce broken AARs in this case too (despite not throwing this error). The following direct local .aar file dependencies of the :tesseract_ocr project caused this error: /home/idunnuoluwa/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/tesseract_ocr-0.3.1/android/libs/tesseract4android-release.aar
```

These are the configurations I had to add
[image]

and this is my tesseract_ocr code

```
_onUnscramble() async {
    _result = await TesseractOcr.extractText(_filePath, language: 'eng');
    setState(() {
      _result = _result;
      _selectedIndex += 1;
    });
  }
```

Please help.

Comment: Did you solve this error? i'm facing the same problem with this plugin.

Comment: I have not. I have even pushed the project to the end of my list